# UITableViewCell gets deleted after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a ToDo list application. For this application, I require a custom UITableViewCell. I am trying to use my custom cell, however, when I run the app and try to scroll through the table view all the cells get deleted.

This is my code:

```
class ToDoListVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TodoCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return HomeVC.ToDoEvents.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! TodoCell
        let eventName = HomeVC.ToDoEvents[indexPath.row].name
        let eventTime = HomeVC.ToDoEvents[indexPath.row].time
        let completion = HomeVC.ToDoEvents[indexPath.row].isComplete

        cell.initialize(task: eventName!, length: eventTime!, completion: completion!)

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    } 
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I went through some of the other threads, however, none of them solved my problem.

Comment: cells get dequeued for reusability. please refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell

Comment: @SuryaKantSharma I'm sorry. I'm not sure I entirely understand your comment. Do you mean I am not dequeuing my cells?

Comment: the cell get reused  for efficiency. Is this is your problem

Comment: Can you show a small video/gif showing what is happening? Also can you post your `numberOfSections` method of tableView datasource? I have a feeling your `HomeVC.ToDoEvents.count` or however you provide the `numberOfSections` is somewhere turning to 0 during scroll

Comment: Agree with @Serj, maybe the problem comes from the line `cell.initialize(task: eventName!, length: eventTime!, completion: completion!)` that effects your `HomeVC.ToDoEvents`. Try printing `HomeVC.ToDoEvents.count` inside that `initialize` method or somewhere you suspect to find out the issue.

Comment: I guess you do something when you call `cell.initialize`:  You may change `HomeVC.ToDoEvents.count` to **0** and `reloadData`. As a result, you could get an empty tableView. You should give us detail about `initialize` method

Comment: You have to use delegate . Pls some research about KVO protocol .